# Access value of nested formgroup Angular

Tags: angular, forms

I have a nested FormGroup as below:

```
formData = new FormGroup({
      item0: this.createForm(),
      item1: this.createForm(),
      item2: this.createForm(),
      item3: this.createForm()
    });
```

each item is a formgroup with 3 properties created by the createForm function:

```
createForm() {
    return new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(undefined, Validators.required),
      imgData: new FormControl(undefined, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(undefined, Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

now I need to access the value inside imgData of, for example, item2, so I tried:

```
formData.controls['item2'].controls['imgData'].value
```

but it has an error: Property 'controls ' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

when I try using .get('imgData') it works just fine, though.

Is there a way to achieve this without `get` and just use with `controls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of ways, you can just get the overall value:

```
formData.value.item2.imgData
```

or cast as FormGroup...

```
(<FormGroup>formData.controls['item2']).controls['imgData'].value;
```

controls and get() both return AbstractControls which may be a control or group or array. you need to tell angular which it is, as controls don't have controls of their own.